# agGroupCellRenderer not found

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I upgraded the ag-grid & ag-grid-react to 14.2.0, but I still get this warning:

> ag-grid: Looking for component [agGroupCellRenderer] but it wasn't found.

My column definitions:

```
let columnDefs = [
    {headerName: 'Name', field: 'userName', width:163, cellRenderer:'agGroupCellRenderer'},
    {headerName: 'Job Title', field: 'jobTitle', width:143},
]
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you resolved this issue, please share what you did to resolve this.

Answer (score 7):

To those who have this message "ag-Grid: Looking for component" with Angular 8, check to see if you have it referenced on your HTML page.  In my code, I was missing some reference code in the HTML file.  Here is a rough example that could help someone:

**EXAMPLE**

**Component File:**

```
import { AgGroupCellRendererComponent } from 
'../../global/components/agGroupCellRenderer.component';

columnDefs= [{headerName: 'Name', field: 'userName', width:163, 
cellRenderer:'agGroupCellRenderer'}]

frameworkComponents: any;
constructor() {
    this.frameworkComponents = {
      agGroupCellRenderer: AgGroupCellRendererComponent,
    };
}
```

**HTML File:**

```
<ag-grid-angular
  style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"
  class="ag-theme-balham"
  [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
  [rowData]="rowData"
  [frameworkComponents]="frameworkComponents"
>
```

Comment: Thanks, you saved my time 2 times because I forget the html part always.

Answer (score 6):

I think you should use components property for mapping string(agGroupCellRenderer) to angular component(AgGroupCellRendererComponent)

```
gridOptions = {
    ... 
    components: {
        agGroupCellRenderer: AgGroupCellRendererComponent
    }
}
```

More information here https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering/

Answer (score 4):

make sure to have in your component file :

```
 frameworkComponents = {agGroupCellRenderer: AGroupCellRenderer}
 context = { componentParent: this }
.....
{headerName: 'Name', field: 'userName', width:163, cellRenderer:'agGroupCellRenderer'}
```

and this in your html file :

```
 <ag-grid-angular 
  ..
    [frameworkComponents]="frameworkComponents"
    [context] = "context"

..>
```

Answer (score 0):

The warning went away when upgraded to 15.0.0

Comment: I'm receiving these errors on aligned grid tables in v17.0.0 despite the cell rendering correctly